# How to set session variables in Java Junit TestCase

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, session, junit

I have written a servlet which uses session variables. I am creating Junit test cases for this flow. But how can I set these session variables in Junit testcase? I use the below code for calling the servlet in Junit testcase:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPostReq = new HttpPost(/url);

    List<NameValuePair> reqParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvpsReqParams.add(); // paramters to add

    httpPostReq.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(reqParams, HTTP.UTF_8));
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPostReq);
```

In between after setting the parameters, I would like to added session variables which are needed by actual usecase. How can I add session variables here?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems as if you were trying to send a request to a servlet already deployed somewhere. It is not the purpose of unit tests. Rather than that, you should test your code (your servlet) in isolation, not deployed to a server.

For that, you need to use mock the web container interfaces your servlet uses. [ServletUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/servletunit-intro.html) is a project that provides such mocks, perhaps have a look at that. Using them, you will be able to set your session parameters.